# Weekly average reports in Redshift

Tags: sql, postgresql, report, amazon-redshift

My sales data for first two weeks of June, Monday Date i.e 1st Jun, 8th Jun are below:

| date | count |
| --- | --- |
| 2015-06-01 03:25:53 | 1 |
| 2015-06-01 03:28:51 | 1 |
| 2015-06-01 03:49:16 | 1 |
| 2015-06-01 04:54:14 | 1 |
| 2015-06-01 08:46:15 | 1 |
| 2015-06-01 13:14:09 | 1 |
| 2015-06-01 16:20:13 | 5 |
| 2015-06-01 16:22:13 | 1 |
| 2015-06-01 16:27:07 | 1 |
| 2015-06-01 16:29:57 | 1 |
| 2015-06-01 19:16:45 | 1 |
| 2015-06-08 10:54:46 | 1 |
| 2015-06-08 15:12:10 | 1 |
| 2015-06-08 20:35:40 | 1 |

I need to find weekly avg of sales for a given range.

Complex Query:

```
(some_manipulation_part), ifact as 
   ( select date, sales_count from final_result_set)
select date_part('h',date )) as h,
       date_part('dow',date )) as day_of_week,
       count(sales_count)
from final_result_set
group by h, dow;
```

Output:

| h | day_of_week | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 |
| 8 | 1 | 1 |
| 10 | 1 | 1 |
| 13 | 1 | 1 |
| 15 | 1 | 1 |
| 16 | 1 | 8 |
| 19 | 1 | 1 |
| 20 | 1 | 1 |

If I try to apply avg on the above final result, it is not actually fetching correct answer!

```
(some_manipulation_part), ifact as 
(select date, sales_count from final_result_set)
select date_part('h',date )) as h,
       date_part('dow',date )) as day_of_week, 
       avg(sales_count) 
from final_result_set
group by h, dow;
```

| h | day_of_week | avg |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 |
| 8 | 1 | 1 |
| 10 | 1 | 1 |
| 13 | 1 | 1 |
| 15 | 1 | 1 |
| 16 | 1 | 1 |
| 19 | 1 | 1 |
| 20 | 1 | 1 |

So I have two Mondays in the given range, it is not actually dividing by it. I am not even sure what is happening inside Redshift.

Comment: Create a `Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example` (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  You could, for example, get the results from ifact for 28 days and push them in to a temporary table.  Then you can both run your outermost query on the temporary table, but also supply us with the example input, the actual output and the expected output.

Comment: updated output also, pls do help me!

Comment: Not sure I understand your expected output.  For example; you have 8 sales at hour 16, but your expected output is 1?  Shouldn't the average be 4?  Also, you mention a date range, how should we know what that range is?  If the range was 1st - 21st, but there are no values on the 15th (3rd Monday in the range), how would we know to divide by 3 instead of 2?

Comment: Actually, I've misunderstood, your third result set is another set of actual results (using AVG rather than COUNT)?  But you have not yet shown us what you expected / wanted the results to be, or why you think that they should be that.  *(And your second set of results look like they come from either a SUM, or from different inputs.)*

Comment: same question.  If the range was 1st - 21st, but there are no values on the 15th (3rd Monday in the range), how would I make the redshift to know to divide by 3 instead of 2 ? ( http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F22759980%2Fgenerate-series-in-redhsift&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNHXKU43mU2RDzAFNnMlEmPS_pt7rw)  And also amazon doesnt support to use generate series along with other tables

Comment: so, I 've 8 sales at hour 16, we should give avg of 4 sales , instead of 1 in the output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82227/discussion-between-error-and-matbailie).

Answer (score 2):

To get "weekly averages" use **`date_trunc()`**.
[Postgres manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC)
[Redshift manual.](https://%20https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATE_TRUNC.html)

```sql
SELECT date_trunc('week', my_date_column) as week
     , avg(sales_count) AS avg_sales
FROM   final_result_set
GROUP  BY 1;
```

If you group by the day of week (`DOW`) you get averages *per weekday*, and Sunday is 0.

Aside: "date" is a reserved word in SQL and a basic type name, don't use it as identifier.